# How much parabolic distortion in residual plots can be tolerated?

Tags: regression, residuals

I have been banging my head against the wall these pas few weeks trying to fit regressions to model outputs and I can't get the parabolic trends out of my residual plots.

First things first:

My model outputs the `Carrot Color` based on `Soil Quality` and `Soil Temperature` inputs.

Plots of model outputs:

[image]

So I tried finding a regression to be able to find the Carrot Color based on the inputs without having to re-run my numerical model every time.

The residual plots I get from it are:

I used the linear regression from the Analysis Toolpack on Excel and fed it the Carrot Color as the ouput, the Log10(Soil Temperature) and Soil Quality as inputs.

[image]

What the graph below shows is that the regression never actually over-estimates massively. It does however, underestimate for value above 10. Can I go along with that as a "conservative approach" as long I as I use the regression on the values within the range of values used to build the regression ?

[image]

EDIT:

Following a suggestion in the comments I tried adding a interaction term of the form Log10(Soil Quality * Soil Temperature). The overall R^2 of the regression reduced slightly, and the P-value of the interaction term is of 0.62

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding an [interaction term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics)#Introduction)?

Comment: No, how would that look like ?

Comment: As in the link I gave: $z = ( a x + b y + c ) + d xy + \mathrm{error}$. So you add $xy$ as an extra "predictor variable", in addition to $x$ and $y$ alone. If $x$ and $y$ are correlated, this extra term would have a "parabolic" component.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.  However I thought that the variables should be independent from one another.  If they have a relationship through an interaction term would that go against it ?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 : I added the interaction term (see EDIT in question), however it's p-value is of 0.62. If my understanding of p-value is correct the closer to 1 the value is the more likely that the coefficient for the variable is due to chance, and that this variable should not be included in the regression.

Comment: did it make the residuals plot noticeably less parabolic? My thought when making the suggestion was that if the interaction term "gets rid of the parabolic residuals", then you could use it to judge their significance.

Comment: Yes, it did reduce it a bit (I've added the residual plot to the edits). So your thought process is that if the factor controlling the parabolicness of the residual is shown to be random (using the P-Value of its coefficient) then the parabolic effects are negligible ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47469/discussion-between-geomatt22-and-sorade).

Comment: Did you try some quadratic terms in the regression? I would try that before interactions ...